# how to use limits in IN clause sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

When running the query

```
select BookID FROM Books_Collection WHERE CollectionID=22 AND BookID IN (SELECT BookID FROM Books LIMIT 0,10);
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

How to use limits with the IN clause? If you can't can you show me how to do this without an IN clause.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Can you supply sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this using a `join` instead:

```
SELECT bc.BookID
FROM Books_Collection bc JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT BookID
      FROM Books
      LIMIT 0,10
     ) b
     ON bc.BookId = b.BookId
WHERE bc.CollectionID = 22;
```

Some notes.  First, using `limit` without an `order by` will give you an arbitrary 10 rows.  They could change from one execution to another.  You should be using an explicit `order by`.

Second, assuming that `BookId` is a valid foreign key, then you may not need to join to `Books`.  You might just want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT bc.BookID
FROM Books_Collection bc 
WHERE bc.CollectionID = 22
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Comment: Thanx they both work, could you please explain what bc is? an abbreviation for books_collection?

Comment: @user3247608 . . . It is called a table alias.  In these queries, it is an abbreviation for the table.  The `b` is an alias for the subquery, which is also required.